# Cassandra slow get_indexed_slices speed

Tags: performance, indexing, cassandra

We are using Cassandra for log collecting.
About 150,000 - 250,000 new records per hour.
Our column family has several columns like 'host', 'errorlevel', 'message', etc and special indexed column 'indexTimestamp'.
This column contains time rounded to hours.

So, when we want to get some records, we use get_indexed_slices() with first IndexExpression by indexTimestamp ( with EQ operator ) and then some other IndexExpressions - by host, errorlevel, etc.

When getting records just by indexTimestamp everything works fine.
But, when getting records by indexTimestamp and, for example, host - cassandra works for long ( more than 15-20 seconds ) and throws timeout exception.

As I understand, when getting records by indexed column and non-indexed column, Cassandra firstly gets all records by indexed column and than filters them by non-indexed columns.

So, why Cassandra does it so slow? By indexTimestamp there are no more than 250,000 records. Isn't it possible to filter them at 10 seconds?

Our Cassandra cluster is running on one machine ( Windows 7 ) with 4 CPUs and 4 GBs memory.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bear in mind that Cassandra is very bad with this kind of queries. Indexed columns queries are not meant for big tables. If you want to search for your data around this type of queries you have to tailor your data model around it.

In fact Cassandra is not a DB you can query. It is a key-value storage system. To understand that please go there and have a quick look: http://howfuckedismydatabase.com/

The most basic pattern to help you is bucket-rows and ranged range-slice-queries.

Let's say you have the object

```
user : {
  name : "XXXXX"
  country : "UK"
  city : "London"
  postal_code :"N1 2AC"
  age : "24"
}
```

and of course you want to query `by city` OR `by age` (`and` & `or` is another data model yet).

Then you would have to save your data like this, assuming the name is a unique id :

```
write(row = "UK", column_name = "city_XXXX", value = {...})
```

AND

```
write(row = "bucket_20_to_25", column_name = "24_XXXX", value = {...})
```

Note that I bucketed by country for the city search and by age bracket for age search.

the range query for age EQ 24 would be

```
get_range_slice(row= "bucket_20_to_25", from = "24-", to = "24=")
```

as a note `"minus" == "under_score" - 1` and  `"equals" == "under_score" + 1`, giving you effectively all the columns that start with "24_"

This also allow you to query for age between 21 and 24 for example.

hope it was useful